# Integration picture with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, integral

[image]how can I reproduce this picture with tikz please.
I tried to export it from GeoGebra, but it doesn't satisfy me.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

```
% Axes
\draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,2);

% Axes labels
\node[below] at (2.5,0) {$x$};
\node[left] at (0,2) {$y$};

% Fonction
\draw[line width=1pt] plot[domain=-1.5:2.5,samples=50] function{x^2};

% Points
\draw[red] (-1.5,2.25) -- (-1.5,0);
\draw[red] (1.5,2.25) -- (1.5,0);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (0,2);

% Texte
\node[red] at (-1.5,2.25) {$a$};
\node[red] at (1.5,2.25) {$a$};
\node[red] at (0,2) {$D$};

% Unité
\draw[black,dashed] (-0.75,-0.2) -- (-0.75,0.2);
\node[black] at (-0.75,0) {1};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: In the pgfmanual tikz.dev look for: \draw, \node, to[out=..,in=..] for a start. Once you have code to show, please post it here, so we can help. Also, there are similar drawings here.

Comment: where can I find similar pictures ?
Can you put the link here please ?

Comment: You could look at [this tutorial in the Ti*k*Z manual](https://tikz.dev/tutorial) to get a basic knowledge about how to draw things with Ti*k*Z. For the curve, you could use the [`plot` operator](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots), but you could also just draw some curve if the curve doesn't need to be exact.

Comment: @Fractal, please. use. this. checklist.  and stop posting fragments today. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No answer, no solution, but a list of requested links.

The key is, to forget about "integration" and perceive more graphical elements, pathes at best (the `Tikz`-way).

- [Area from a circular segment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429468/tikz-draw-integral)
- [discrete integration visualized](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30763/timing-and-integration-with-tikz-pgflots)
- [areas under a function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630448/how-do-you-graph-the-definite-integral-of-1-x-from-1-to-1)
- [hatched fill of intersecting curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431458/fill-integral-exponent-function)
- [colorful discrete integral](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667646/lebesgue-integral-on-tikz)
- [a flood of topics done by Tikz](https://tikz.net/topics/)

You also may follow tags, like [integral](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral) .

As Jasper pointed out, spend time on, and trials from and with, the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/) ...